# Auto populate cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

19/09/22 - Edit

I've attached a picture of the spreadsheet.

Basically, if I were to select any price from the table, I would like it to populate the price cell in B17.

Then with the discount cell set at 20% (E17) The discounted price is worked out automatically in cell H17 using autosum.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjH3r.jpg)I'm creating a pricing spreadsheet for our customers. Different costs are based on different heights and widths we manufacture.

I've created an X and Y table with each cost populating the applicable cell based on their required height and width.

We offer a discount so I'm looking for a way for the customer to click on the cost in the table based on their requirement, that cost then populates a cell below the table where I can then use those cells to autosum based on their percentage discount.

I'm very basic when it comes excel so any help would be appreciated.

Hope this explains it a little clearer.

Comment: Post few sample data and show your desired output.

Comment: Hi Harun24hr, just added a picture and further explanation.